# Vim - delete line in insert mode

Tags: vim, vi

Can I delete a line in insert mode?

Because currently I have to press `<ESC>dd` to be able to that, and I would like a quicker way to delete a line in insert mode

Comment: sure look up how to map key commands

Comment: can't I do it without key mapping ?

Comment: in insert mode? if there is , i am not aware.. sorry

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the cursor is at the end of the line, you can press `<C-U>` twice. The first one will clear the text before the cursor, the second one will remove the now empty line (and put the cursor at the end of the previous line).

That said, I would not use this often. Insert mode is for *inserting*; for all other edits, it's better to exit insert mode and use normal mode `dd` instead. Most power users quickly move into and out of various modes; that's what they were made for. Don't linger in insert mode for too long. I even exit it for "thinking pauses" of more than a few seconds.

Comment: absolutly agree with Ingo here. if `<ESC>dd` is too inconvenient you may have a look at: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key. Also compared to other editors, `<ESC>dd` seems rather fast to me.

Comment: This worked beautifully - I assumed `<C-U>` is actually `Ctrl+U` (depending on your mapping of course)

this is a note for the reader too

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this is `Ctrl+U`; I'm using the same notation as in Vim's mappings (`:help key-notation`).

Comment: I tend to use <C-U>, <C-W> which are command line commands and not Vim commands (in my opinion) since I can use them in the CLI outside Vim. However, you lose the power of Vim since you can't paste what you have just delete like you can do in Edit mode. I only use them if I'm not going to use the text I'm deleting

Answer (score 30):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in Insert mode to run one Normal mode command, so you can delete the current line without leaving Insert mode, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O

Comment: I would prefer this since it still keeps me in insert mode

Comment: Great answer, I also prefer this.

Comment: Wow, after almost 20 years years of using Vim, you taught me something today.
`:h i_CTRL-O` is included in the section *Special special keys*.

Answer (score 14):

Press `c` + `c` (press c twice) will delete current line and enter insert mode.

Comment: `Esc c c` sounds as the closest thing to the request.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `_` to jump to first non-whitespace character and then `C` to delete to end of line and start insert.

You won't be in insert mode at the beginning, but you will be after running `C`. You also save yourself an `esc` keystroke and won't have to worry about mappings. Using `_` also makes it easier to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating an insert mapping

```
inoremap <Leader>k <C-o>dd
```

Remember  in most cases is mapped to ",". For more information type: `:h mapleader`