# How to undo pressing Ctrl-U in Insert mode to avoid accidentally losing my work

Tags: vim

If you're like me and often [use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to enter special characters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31258/how-can-i-type-a-unicode-character-for-example-em-dash) (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>2014</kbd> to enter `—`), you may have occasionally accidentally gotten the timing wrong and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> instead (pressing the <kbd>U</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> but just before pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

<sup>(For me, it's even easier to fat finger since I usually press all 3 of those keys with my left hand (I use Dvorak) so that I can leave my right hand on their home keys.)</sup>

But if you make this mistake while in Insert mode, you can **inadvertently and permanently lose an entire line of input—without any way to get it back**. Wait, wat!?

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> "Deletes all entered characters before the cursor in the current line." See `:help i_CTRL-U` or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48163933/47185))

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> does not undo this deletion, like it would if I had deleted the line with <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>. (Even pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> *without leaving* insert mode does not work).

Needless to say, if you've just spent several minutes or an hour composing a really long paragraph (which will be considered a single line if you haven't inserted any line breaks) without leaving Insert mode, it can be very disheartening and disconcerting to vainly press <kbd>u</kbd>, expecting to get your line back but having it instead revert back to an even *earlier* undo state! The confidence you've placed in your trusty editor, vim, suddenly gets dashed to pieces as you dolefully realize that you now have to try to remember what you just wrote and compose it all over again.

I can think of a few *workarounds* to try to make editing safer, like trying to remember to exit insert mode frequently so that a new undo block is created (see `:help undo-blocks`)...

But I shouldn't *have* to tread so carefully when composing something. I should be able to stay in the flow (that is, keep composing without leaving Insert mode) as long as the words keep flowing. (And it's probably safe to say that most editors don't have this problem. In most editors, Undo would undo your changes one character at a time since they don't have any way to group multiple characters together as a single "insert").

Since I probably won't remember to be so careful, I ended up simply disabling use of Ctrl-U altogether in Insert mode, for now, with this:

```
imap <C-U> <Nop>
```

---

But what I'd like to know is if there's any decent way to make Ctrl-U still *work* in case I ever want to use it, *but create an undo state* so that this deletion can be easily undone with <kbd>U</kbd>. Is this possible? (And why isn't this the default behavior?)

Comment: See https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Recover_from_accidental_Ctrl-U

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for! And nice to see that there _is_ a way to get the deleted text back—from the `.` register (`:echo @.`). Phew! Confidence in vim restored. Feel free to post that as an Answer.

Comment: What version of vim are you using? I tried to reproduce your problem before seeing the answer in the comment here, and with my vim 8.1 `Esc u` did undo the `Ctrl-U` and give me back the text. If you're using an older version of vim, I recommend upgrading, several bugs and annoying issues have been fixed in recent versions. Ah, just tested on a vim 7.4 I have elsewhere, and indeed I see your problem. So I'd say if you can update vim, that would be your best solution.